# Assign id to element on click and then run scrolld.js function

Tags: jquery, function, events, onclick, element

I am trying to combine an on click event with a function in jQuery but somehow it only works after the second click.

On click, at first I need the id of the element to be changed to what I give it and then the function needs to catch the element with the changed id and run.

I cannot work with classes here unfortunately so I have to change the element id on click.

```
$('.element').click(function()
// here the element gets id "divBtn"
    {if(this.id){this.id = "divBtn";}

// this is the function I need to run on the above first click
// this function is also the trigger to call scrolld.js (scrolldjs.com) so I am not sure if I
// can modify this part or not
    $("[id*='Btn']").stop(true).on('click',function(e)
        {e.preventDefault();                    
    $(this).scrolld();


});
```

});

In the second line the id of the element is changed to "divBtn" with the first click. That works and can be seen in the console.

However only after the second click though the function catches the element with id "divBtn" and runs.

How can I combine this into one click?

New with jQuery and learning so this might be pretty obvious. Thank you heaps for any help or input. If you have an answer, if you don't mind, please comment your code or explain in enough detail since I am just starting out with jQuery. Thank you.

EDIT 01: Please note the script/function I need to run on the element only works with elements that have an id and "Btn" at the end of the id, hence I need to use an id for the element. If it is possible to get rid of the second click and run the function that would go be it I guess.

EDIT 02: Here is a **working** jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ASzTg/10/ where you can see the id changing in the browser console on first click. Then the second click catches the scrolld script and does its job. From the jsfiddle you can see what I am trying to get at, a click from the nav bar links nicely scrolls the desired div to the position I want (or any other).

Scrolld is used to scroll the content-wrapper to desired position (top or any other) once any of the nav bar links are clicked. Since Scrolld only accepts an id I have to assign the id on click and then run the script.

Hope this helps what I am trying to do. If you see http://scrolldjs.com/#use you can see the trigger, this might explain the two event handlers. Hope this helps find the right answer.

Regards

Comment: This makes no sense, event handlers inside event handler, using stop() for no apparent reason, changing the ID of some element to make it work with an event handler, and curlybraces used in the strangest of ways?

Comment: on the second line, if you are setting your id to divBtn, why do you check if the id is divBtn again in the next line? Also if you are setting your div id to "divBtn" why are you binding click event to id="Btn"? Isn't it supposed to be $("[id*='divBtn']").on('click',function(e)

Comment: The function catches all elements with id "Btn" at the end and then scrolls the viewport to the top of that element or to a desired other position. Since I cannot make the function work with classes I have to assign the (anchor) element with the "Btn" id with a click since I cannot have multiple anchors with the same id in html. The trigger function is given here scrolldjs.com and taken as is. If I can modify it that would be great. Sorry for the strange formatting just starting with jQuery.

Comment: @moderntimes you know, ids are unique. Meaning that you can not have same ids for multiple elements. So you can not have multiple elements with id="Div". Also using [id*='Btn'] doesn't make sense, since you can only have one id, you can simply use $('#Btn') selector.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can you not use classes? Obviously classes are currently present for you to have to change them to id's.

Comment: @Caner Akdeniz Before the new id is assigned by click to the desired elements all of them have various ids since ids have to be unique in html, yes. Using [id*='Btn'] is part of scrolld.js' (scrolldjs.com) initializing function, checking if an element has Btn at the end and then running the script on the element. Hence I think I need to leave that part. However if I can somehow get rid of the second click event that would possibly help. Though not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Mark I cannot use classes since the script/function only catches elements with an id unfortunately. Otherwise I would be fine, yes. I cannot change the script/function, so I have to find a way to adapt it to the use I intend it for. Thank you for any help with this. Check out scrolldjs.com/#use and you will see it needs to be an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the second event handler completely - There's no need to bind 2 click event handlers to the same element

```
$('.element').click(function (e)  { // bind event handler to element/s
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    if (this.id) {
        this.id = "divBtn"; // add id if it doesn't have one
    }        
    $(this).scrolld(); // run your method
});
```

Though if you have multiple `.element` elements - they will end up with the same id which is invalid HTML

Comment: I think I need the second click event handler since it checks if the clicked element has the id "divBtn" and then runs the function/script scrolld.js on it. With my code only after the second click the function/script works since with the first click the id was changed. Trying to merge the two event handlers and click with as little change as possible to the second initializing function taken from scrolldjs.com.

Comment: Can you show a markup and maybe make a fiddle?  Is this only one element or multiple elements?  So do some of the elements already have a different ID?  I'm assuming you can just use delegation to do what you want but it's unclear exactly what your setup is

Comment: If you check out scrolldjs.com/#use you will see the trigger function. For a demo you can check see srolldjs.com/demo/. The way I want to use this is that when clicking any of the desired elements the div moves to the assigned position. So basically assigning multiple anchors to one target. Adding more markup..

Comment: Added jsfiddle and hoping you can see what I am trying to do. Basically have a set of links with class scrolld. Then I click on those link, the id ...Btn is assigned, what leads to scrolld.js picking up on the link and scrolling the target id to the desired position.

Comment: The new jsfiddle now also works. If you click the first time the id is changed, the second time the script catches the id. Now this only needs to be one step now. Hope this helps find a reply. Thank you for any any help you still might be able to offer. Regards

Comment: I did try it your way and it works! Thank you heaps! What about .stop(true)? Does that not have to be included? I guess I did not understand your answer at first and had some errors so it did not work at first. Now it does and I am super glad. Thank you! **Now the last thing that comes to mind is: how do I give the element the old id back once clicked and script ran?** I guess that is another topic, however if you could add the code and it is a simple one liner that would solve ALL my issues here. Gosh how I love jQUery! Also many thanks to you!